# Exclude deleted value in an array when doing a Math.Random

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find a way to remove a letter (A,B,C) when I click three times on a button, I tried to use `delete`, because I don't want to use `splice`, because `splice` will change the order of the array. I want the variables `letterA`, `letterB` and `letterC` to keep their position on the array. What I was looking for was something like: `if (randomletters == undefined)` do math.random again, until it gets something different to undefined, maybe using a while.

I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any solution for my problem? Please don't use jQuery, just normal JS.

```js
var A = 0;
var B = 0;
var C = 0;

function incrementA() { A++; }
function incrementB() { B++; }
function incrementC() { C++; }


var letters = new Array()
letters[0] = 'letterA'
letters[1] = 'letterB'
letters[2] = 'letterC'
var randomletter;


function random() {
  if (A == 3) { delete letters[0]; }
  if (B == 3) { delete letters[1]; }
  if (C == 3) { delete letters[2]; }

  if ((A == 0 || A == 3) && (B == 0 || B == 3) && (C == 0 || C == 3)) {
    randomletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length));
    if (randomletter == undefined) {
      do {
        randomletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length));
      } while(randomletter != undefined)
    }
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = letters[randomletter];
  }
}
```

```css
#green {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
}

#text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" onclick="random()"> </div>
<button id="green" onclick="incrementA()">A </button>
<button id="green" onclick="incrementB()">B </button>
<button id="green" onclick="incrementC()">C </button>
```

Comment: Just a hint, you can use `var letters = ['letterA','letterB','letterC'];` and save yourself a few lines :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implemented the wrong comparison operator, and need to check the element, not the index.

your `random()` function should be something like:

```
function random() {
  if (A == 3) { delete letters[0]; }
  if (B == 3) { delete letters[1]; }
  if (C == 3) { delete letters[2]; }

  if ((A == 0 || A == 3) && (B == 0 || B == 3) && (C == 0 || C == 3)) {
    do {
      randomletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length));
    } while (letters[randomletter] == undefined)
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = letters[randomletter];
  }
}
```

The do-while ensures that `randomletter` is set once, then keeps setting it if the chosen value is undefined. You might want to add a check for "at least one element is valid" before the do-while begins or you could have an infinite loop scenario.

For example:

```
if (A > 2 && B > 2 && C > 2) {
   // all elements of letters are undefined
} else if ((A == 0 || A == 3) && (B == 0 || B == 3) && (C == 0 || C == 3)) {
   // do-while loop, because at least one element is valid
}
```

Comment: @John you need to check the element, not the index. I just edited

Comment: It works! the only problem now is that if I click three times on each button, at the end the page crashes. What I was going to do if this worked 100% was just to add an alert ("You win"), do you have any solution for this ? Thank you

Comment: When all 3 are undefined, you have an infinite loop. I recommended in my answer that you should add a check for this case, the case where there are no valid elements left.  Probably the best place for this check is in the `if`, i.e. `if (A > 2 && B > 2 && C > 2) { alert("you win"); } else if (<your existing condition> ) {...`